# Where does pycharm store project data and can it be recovered?

Tags: pycharm

I used pycharm to do my project. Later due to some hardware issue I has to restore my laptop. Now all softwares are gone. Is there any way to get back that project code? My whole project is in that pycharm. Is there any way or any softwares available to recover it. Will pycharm use any cloud storage. Will I be able to recover it?

Answer (score 1):

**No**, PyCharm is just an IDE, it does not automatically backup your project to anywhere.